# Jenkins multi-configuration job and MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm looking for a way to pass user-defined axis values to a free-style job that uses MSBuild. Let me explain.

So we have JobA which is a multi-configuration project that only has one axis (key1) and multiple value (foo and bar). I also have a free-style job called JobB which uses MSBuild to *build* a specific project within a solution.

I was wondering how I could pass the values (foo and bar) of the axis (key1) of JobA to JobB so that JobB could use it in the command line arguments of the MSBuild plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be the Parameterized Trigger Plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

You can use it in JobA (as a post-build action, I believe) to set triggers for JobB to build with.
This way you could pass foo and bar into variables for JobB, and use them on the command line.